# Multiple applications in single solution

Tags: c#, winforms, client, multiple-projects

I believe this is possible but unsure how to go around it,  I need to create a server/client solution, normally I would create a new solution for the server and a new one for the client however I am looking to do this within a single solution as they would both be using the same custom classes and don't really want the issue of having to change the same file twice.

So the question is can I create multiple exe's within a single solution and what are the steps to achieve this.

I have searched on here but don't fully understand the procedure so if someone can point me in the general right direction it would be great. :)

VS2010 using C Sharp and Windows Forms

Comment: Just add as many projects as you want and build your solution.

Comment: Are you looking for [Multi-project solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23x5fk78.aspx)?

Comment: I think before one can trully answer your question you need to be more specific as to what type of application this Client Server will do.. is it a traditional FAT Client, Thin Client, WPS,etc.. then specify what the app is suppose to do and one can suggest a valid soulution from there..

Comment: The system should basicly output two executable files, the install using ISS would then pick the correct one to install, it is a simple support desk software so there is a program for the clients to have installed in their notification area, and another one on the companies machines so when a new ticket is raised it pops up a notification.

Comment: Do you mean threading or threat surface analysis, @mekici

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Please see **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711038/can-i-avoid-duplicating-my-business-layer-net/8711677#8711677)** and **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755801/anyone-have-experience-with-architecture-for-cross-platform-wp7-android-ios-mobi)** previous answer which I gave on cross-platform client server application development, specifically with code-reuse across multiple clients. This is also applicable to your Winforms client server app here.

As many answers are saying, you can structure your solution in order to share code as follows:

**Project Structure**

> Solution
>   .. Common       (Messages, Datacontracts, Utilities)
>   .. Middleware   (References Common, provides common services)
>   .. .. Server Exe   (References Common, Middleware)
>   .. .. Client Exe   (References Common, Middleware)

**Top level client-server architecture**

[image: Cross-platform application stack]

**Your stack becomes**

> Clients:

Client has serialization, client side implementations of webservices/middleware and [Model-View-Presenter patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter) for the view.

> Middleware:

Middleware, i.e. shared services and data transport implemetation on server / client desktop can be the same. Alternatively you could call this Services. Any specific services for client only (or server only) should go in separate assemblies and referenced only by the specific exe (client or server). i.e. dont share code that isn't shared!

> Messages/DataContracts:

Shared across all clients/server using the techniques I outlined above. In your case these may be common domain objects shared between client and server

> Server:

All business logic, DB access and server-side service implementations. For DB Access I'd recommend [PetaPoco](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/) as an excellent MicroORM.

**Development and debugging**

Yes, a solution can have more than one exe, simply use [set Startup Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1awth7y.aspx) by right clicking on Server Exe or Client Exe to debug one or the other.

If you wish to **run the client and server together,** you can run both from the command line and attach the debugger to both processes.

Best regards,

Comment: @Neo thank you! I hope it wasn't overkill. I got the impression from your question you were also unsure of general client/server architecture not just project setup. The project part is actually very easy in VS2010. Just add multiple Exe's and use the Set Startup Project. The difficult part is how to partition your code to enable efficient sharing and re-use of key logic, classes etc. My advice, don't create too many projects. I worked on one app recently with 97 projects in a client/server environment :( That and use interfaces / abstractions and above all **Dependency Injection**

Comment: Hi Andy, nope not overkill at all no such thing in my book :)  I have integrated several client server apps using a custom php api I created so the integration isn't an issue it was just mainly the VS side of things as its not the most friendly of environments!  I am interested in several of the items you meantioned in your post, MVP? MVVM? Also do you have further information on PetaPoco as it sounds interesting.

Comment: @Neo apologies a lot of the above is a re-hash of previous questions (as disclaimed). I will edit out MVVM as it is not applicable in your case for winforms. MVP is `Model View Presenter` which I suggest you look up as a best practice for developing GUI code in winforms. Petapoco is a C# Object Relational Mapping library - 1500 lines - its micro but its very powerful. If your server is implemented in php this will also not be applicable

Answer (score 2):

First, ensure you can see the solution file in the solution explorer:

Go to `Tools->Options`. Then under `Projects and Solutions` ensure `Always Show Solutions` is checked.

Then, in the solution explorer (top right, where your project's files are) right click on your solution (just above your project icon) then click `Add->New Project`.

---

In terms of the layout of the solution, you'd have 3 projects, the client project, the server project, and a class library project of shared classes.

Your client and server projects would reference the library project, see: [Project Reference (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

---

See also: [Multi-Project Solutions (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23x5fk78.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You would do it like this:

1. Have one solution
2. Add three projects to the solution:

   1. Project A: The server exe
   2. Project B: The client exe
   3. Project C: A class library project containing the classes that projects A and B use.
3. Make project A and B reference project C

Answer (score 1):

You can right click on solution icon located at the top in the solution explorer and choose add new project option.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a new  Class Library project to your solution. Put your common code in there.
2. Add as a many WinForms projects you need to your solution.
3. Add references to the Class Library project to your winforms projects.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special about multiple project within a single solution - VS 2010 supports this fully, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23x5fk78.aspx .

Answer (score 1):

You can also add the **same project** to **multiple solutions**. There is no need to have both the server and client output in a single solution.

In other words, if these are the projects you want to use in both server and client:

```
Project A: CoreClasses
Project B: Entities
```

Then simply add them to both solutions:

```
 + Solution 1: Server
   +- Project A: CoreClasses
   +- Project B: Entities
   +- Project C: ServerSpecific -> output

 + Solution 2: Client
   +- Project A: CoreClasses
   +- Project B: Entities
   +- Project D: ClientSpecific -> output
```

In your `trunk`, it would look something like:

```
 /trunk/
 /trunk/ProjectA/
 /trunk/ProjectB/
 /trunk/ProjectC/
 /trunk/ProjectD/
 /trunk/ClientSolution.sln
 /trunk/ServerSolution.sln
```